# Java lambda only throwing expression-style instead of statement-style

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, throw, functional-interface

In Java (using Java 8 currently), I can write this and all will compile nice and well:

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> {
    throw new RuntimeException();
};
```

Yet, I cannot write this:

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> throw new RuntimeException(); // This won't compile :(
```

Does anyone know why Java's implementation does not allow such style (expression lambda) and only the statement/code-block style lambda?

I mean, since the lambda is *only* throwing the RuntimeException, why isn't the JDK able to infer the lambda expression as:

```
new Supplier<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long get() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
};
```

Is this documented somewhere in the specs/docs? Is this added only in JDK > 8?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `{}` surrounding your statement `throw new RuntimeException()` is an "anonymous function". my guess is that the devs decided that all calls should be in a method, and not in the style you are asking for. this is in no way authoritative, hence the comment, rather than an answer...

Comment: You can not use the expression syntax, because a `throw` statement is not an expression. As simple as that.

Comment: because throw is not an expression in the same way as return is not an expression perhaps?

Comment: Note: [C# got *throw expressions* in version 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#throw-expressions). It might be a good idea to propose such a feature for Java as well (especially if Java ever gets a null coalescing operator, because that seems to be the main use case for throw expressions in C#).

Answer (score 23):

From the language spec [JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> A lambda body is either a single expression or a block (§14.2).

`throw` is not a single expression (it's a statement); so you have to use it in a block.

Answer (score 18):

What you wrote is an invalid lambda. There is a difference between the expression with the brackets `{}` and without. See the example. The following means that `1L` is returned.

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> 1L;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> {
    return 1L;
};
```

However, when you write:

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> throw new RuntimeException();
```

It would be translated following which is an *invalid* lambda:

```
Supplier<Long> asd = () -> {
     return throw new RuntimeException();                    // invalid expression in Java
};
```

In a nutshell, you can understand `() -> 1L` as a shortcut for `{ return 1L; }`.

Comment: This is not entirely the case, since the following program is valid: `Consumer<String> consumer = str -> System.out.println(str)`. This is not elaborated to `Consumer<String> consumer = str -> { return System.out.println(str); }` (which would similarly be an invalid program). Some special rules were added to accommodate expressions of type `void`; it's just that these same rules weren't added to accommodate `throw` statements.